# Разные точки входа для форума и остального сайта

Tags: apache, nginx

Apache на 8888.
Nginx на 80.
В конфинге нгингса все пхпшные запросы шлются в апач

```
location ~ \.php$ {
  root /var/www/web/;
  ssi on;
  proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8888;
}
```

В апаче так

```
<VirtualHost *:8888>
    LogLevel info
    ServerName testserver.localhost

    DocumentRoot /var/www/web/

    <Directory /var/www/web>
        AllowOverride none
        DirectoryIndex index.php
        AddType application/x-httpd-php .php
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Но надо, чтобы testserver.localhost/forum/* имел точку входа /var/www/forum/index.php

В какую сторону копать? Мне нужно в апаче прописать новый Directory? Подтолкните плиз.

Answer (score 0):

> В какую сторону копать? Мне нужно в апаче прописать новый Directory? Подтолкните плиз.

`http://testserver.localhost/forum/` не может быть доменным корнем (корнем виртуалхоста).

Нужно просто установить форум в каталог `/var/www/web/forum/` а не в `/var/www/forum/` и никуда ничего не прописывать не нужно. (если непременно файлы хочется держать в `/var/www/forum/`, то можно сделать симлинки, но это того ИМХО не стоит - проблем больше будет)

Разными вируталхосты могут быть если захотеть `http://forum.testserver.localhost/`. Тогда можно и в `/var/www/forum/` разместить.